# Why am I getting this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am doing this in Ruby:

```
 irb(main):001:0> class Fixnum
 irb(main):002:1>   define_method(:previous) do
 irb(main):003:2*     self.-(1)
 irb(main):004:2>   end
 irb(main):005:1> end
```

When I press enter, I get this:

```
=> #<Proc:0x007f90a18074e0@(irb):2 (lambda)>
irb(main):006:0>
```

Apparently, I am supposed to get =>:previous but I get the above. The code still works though. When I enter:

```
irb(main):006:0> 3.previous()
```

I get:

```
=>2
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? What should I do so that I get =>:previous?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running? If I define that class in Ruby 1.8.7, it comes back with `=> #<Proc:0xb75e4928@(irb):2>`. In Ruby 2.2.1, I get `=> :previous`. It's what the class definition action itself returned.

Comment: I see. I am running 2.0.0 when I type in ruby -v

Comment: Well it's changed since 2.1.0. I think is [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3753). Pre 2.1.0 def's returned `nil` and `define_method` lambdas

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing you are doing wrong.

In Ruby, *everything* returns a value. Even the action of defining a class or method. IRB thinks it's being helpful by showing you the return value of your call to `class Fixnum`. However, it's not really very helpful, especially since you're not using it or assigning it to a variable.

As other commenters pointed out, your tutorial was written for a slightly different version of Ruby than the one you're using, so the walkthrough is slightly wrong.

If it's not too much trouble for you, you should upgrade to the latest Ruby, since the language's features, stability and performance have improved a lot since version 2.0.0.

Comment: thank you. would you happen to know of a tutorial to update to 2.2.1 on yosemite? or maybe you can tell me if https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx0NrIbQbzI is the right way?

Comment: That tutorial uses rbenv. I prefer [rvm](http://rvm.io) but both are fine. There are also a few other "upgrading Ruby to Yosemite" SO answers and blog posts. Basically upgrade Homebrew first (`brew update`) and install the lastest OS X dev tools before doing anything with Ruby and you should be fine.